# C# Array (Repeated Element)

Tags: c#

Given an array for example

```
int[] x = {2,5,5};
```

How can I find if the element is repeated. Some simplest way please.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want? Do you want to know all repeating elements or check if a certain one is repeated? Also, would 2,5,2 count as repeated or just consecutive repeats?

Comment: Yes, I am getting into trouble when iterating.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the element is repeated"? Does the repeat need to be consecutive?

Comment: Just need to return true or false. If the element is repeated then true if not then false. I tried some iteration but getting confuse

Comment: You still didn't define what you mean by "the element is repeated".

Comment: @JasmineAppelblad: If *which* element is repeated? And consecutively or not?

Comment: @Jon, any element if it's repeated more than once.

Comment: @JasmineAppelblad: Repeated immediately, or just anywhere? For example would `{ 5, 2, 5 }` could or not?

Comment: @Jon, Just anywhere in the series. {5,2,5} is repeated value yes.

Comment: @JasmineAppelblad: Right - that cuts out my suggested answer. This is why it's important to be clear in questions.

Comment: @Jon, you're Abs(-right) but sometimes I just can't explain what I want to ask! :) Lolz!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the repeat doesn't need to be consecutive:

```
 x.Length!=x.Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: Should that be `Array.length - 2` to avoid an OOB exception from `arr[i+1]`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, you just removed chaos from my code. It was full of if else for for for and now just a line.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Brain must have not been working when I posted that!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been answered already, but maybe this will interest you:

```
bool isRepeated = false;
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < x.Length; j++)
    {
        if (x[i] == x[j])
        {
            isRepeated = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isRepeated) break;
}
Text = isRepeated.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you ispiro, indeed it's of great help and an addition in my notebook! :)